# .NET-compatible Web Service/ API for AMEX Corporate Card statements?

Tags: c#, api, credit-card

Is there such a thing?  I would assume yes, but I have been unable to find one.  I am trying to collect activity line items to automate expense report processing, and I thought this would be an elegant way of doing so.

I'm hoping my google-fu is weak and there is actually an API available that I can use for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yodlee may be helpful here, see e.g. http://www.yodlee.com/developers-and-alliances/ . "Yodlee's Aggregation APIs give permission-based access to users' financial accounts, including banks, cards, investments, loans and bills."

Comment: Meh... I wasn't happy with this, but it's a legit answer.